# Can uppercase j be used to replace uppercase i letter on a monument inscription?

Tags: vocabulary, alphabet

I have seen it repeatedly on two grave inscriptions. Both were called Ida but there was Jda on the grave inscription. They lived in the 19th and 20th centuries in the Central Europe.

Is this a linguistic phenomenon? Like writing V instead of U in Latin language historical inscriptions?

Using V instead of U makes some sense to me. The original Latin alphabet written with modern equivalent letters is:

A B C D E F Z H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X

where is no U, so it is logical to use V as U. This reasoning fails to explain why there could be I replaced by J, if in the above alphabet, there is I but not J...

Thank you.

Comment: Are those grave inscriptions in Latin?

Comment: Like Draconis mentioned below, they are "inventions" of late in Latin. People use those different versions in order to distinguish the sounds they make : v when the letter is pronounced as w in English, and u like the sound in "put" (think of it like writing put and fun in different ways -like IPA- in English) same for i when it is voiced as "ee" and "j" like "y" in "you".

Answer (score 3):

I and J were historically the same letter; using I for the vowel and J for the consonant was a relatively late innovation. So in older inscriptions you may find I's that look like modern J's, and vice versa: it just wasn't a distinction that was used at that time.

Comment: Both graves I have seen were of people who died in the 20th century. Also, I have just found a river "JLL", that in German is read as the word "ill" in English. A question can be when was the river named..